Google Cloud OAuth 2.0 missing client secret
I'm trying to get the client ID and client secret from Google Cloud for my Unity game to use Google Play Games. However when I download the credentials, there is only the client_id but not client_secret in the JSON. I'm lost since I don't know where else I could find the client secret.



It seems that for the Play Games Services to be used with unity you need to create the OAuth client with "web application" and not "andorid" type even if the google play console tells you to use android. I also found this confusing because the JSON from android client was named client_secret_...json even though it didn't have any client_secret.
I'm going to leave this here if anyone runs into the same confusion, even if it might be a stupid question.
